# Elegant way to update many properties with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model with 7 properties and want to update them all when there is an edit request from front-end. Is there any elegant way to do so, or do I have to type all of them manually like in my code bellow (whitch by the way works fine for me, but looks really ugly).

```
exports.saveDish = (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    name,
    description,
    price,
    category,
    vegetarian,
    hot,
    menuPosition,
  } = req.body;
  Dish.findById(req.body._id)
    .then(oldDish => {
      if (oldDish) {
        oldDish.name = name;
        oldDish.description = description;
        oldDish.price = price;
        oldDish.category = category;
        oldDish.vegetarian = vegetarian;
        oldDish.hot = hot;
        oldDish.menuPosition = menuPosition;
        oldDish.save();
        return res.status(204).json({ message: 'Dish data properly updated' });
      }
      const newDish = new Dish(req.body);
      newDish.save();
      return res.status(201).json({ message: 'New dish properly saved' });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Have you tried the Mongoose model method `findByIdAndUpdate`? Sounds like it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update an existing record and return the updated value. If no matching record is found, it will return a falsey value to the callback or promise (can't remember if it's `null` or something else).

```
Dish.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, updates, {new: true}, cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
exports.saveDish = (req, res, next) => {

    /**
     * 
     * upsert: true --> helps to insert new document if no matching doc exists
     * new: true --> returns new document in output
     * rawResult: true --> helps to find out whether update or insert operation is done 
     * 
     * Dish is a mongoose schema where findByIdAndUpdate is only from mongoose,
     * which internally converts a string from it's first parameter into {_id : ObjectId('req.body._id')}, also uses $set operation on req.body
     *
     * Print data to check what's being returned, you might see entire document(data.value) being returned with some other information
     *
     * */

    Dish.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, { upsert: true, new: true, rawResult: true }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err); res.status(200).json({ message: 'Operation Failed' }) }
        if (data.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting) return res.status(204).json({ message: 'Dish data properly updated' });
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'New dish properly saved' });
    })
};
```

Here you're updating existing document (adding new fields or updating the existing fields w.r.t. what's there is req.body) or inserting an entire new document if no matching `_id` is found in database, this way you avoid multiple DB calls. Here I've made it in callbacks, but earlier I've actually done it in `async` `await`, it does work either way, this should work for all of your cases listed above !!

**Ref :** [Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Answer (score 0):

@EddieDean, your way worked almost fine, it turns out that you have to pass any id to findByIdAndUpdate() method, so I edited it a little bit to work with unique, new dishes too.

Working code just in case:

```
exports.saveDish = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body._id) {
    Dish.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body._id },
      { ...req.body },
      { useFindAndModify: false }
    )
      .then(oldDish => {
        if (oldDish) {
          oldDish.save();
          return res
            .status(204)
            .json({ message: 'Dish data properly updated' });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  } else {
    const newDish = new Dish(req.body);
    newDish
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'New dish properly saved' });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};
```